# Building blocks for a website with good search and is very responsive

Tags: search, frameworks

I have a project in mind whose main selling point would be very good search results and very responsive (another Google for domain specific data). I'm not worried much about scaling at this point.

Whats the best ORM, Search and UI framework combinations can one choose and what are the pros and cons. I'm mainly a Java programmer but this one is worth learning any new language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

will use [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) and [Sphinx Search](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/) helped by [Django-Sphinx](http://code.google.com/p/django-sphinx/)

Answer (score 1):

It would be worth looking at [Hibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/344.html) with [Hibernate Search](https://www.hibernate.org/410.html), which uses [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/) under the covers for indexing.

The UI framework you use is somewhat orthogonal to this - while some frameworks do come with their own ORMs, you should be able to use Hibernate from just about any framework.

Comment: on UI i was looking at Wicket, JSF with Facelets, Tapestry etc, or other none Java frameworks for that matter. For example after reading this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281475/wicket-page-stack-and-memory-usage one would say Wicket is not the best to choose in this case.